# trouble with mysql data connect trouble

Tags: mysql, database

i have a problem with my website,
 i get a Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL. error.
the tech support told that: "A script is not closing the MySQL connection after accessing the database. Please make sure that you close the connection immediately after accessing the database using mysql_close() command from your scripts."

And I didn't make any change recently.
can anyone advise?

Comment: `And I didn't make any change recently. can anyone advise?`. My advice: Make it! Close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to some uncaught exception in accessing DB, it won't have any problem til there is nothing unexpected as result/entries. but when some unexpected result/ entry comes. then the query may break flow of execution , and may not go through the db close() statement. Make sure nothing unexpected in your DB/ no unusual content.